# set Lines on map From Point A to Point b

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working On Map project and i have to use Lines From A Point To B point. now have to touch a Lines and move over the map . is any one have Knowledge about this. i have search a lot in internet but did not get any clue. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK It is not feasible because we use google map SDK which just provides the info which already there. we can't edit or delete anything there.

Comment: I think you can get something from here--- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker